# Launch WPF on Secondary Display?

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a simple way to cause a (full screen) WPF app to launch on a secondary display? I know I could get the entire virtual desktop rectangle and calculate an offset, but is there a more direct way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK there is currently no way to do this purely with WPF.

However you should be able to:

- Use the `System.Windows.Forms.Screen` class to get information about the screen(s)
- Reposition your window:

  `Application.Current.MainWindow.Left = xxx;`
  `Application.Current.MainWindow.Top = yyy;`

Comment: But accessing "System.Windows.Forms.Screen" will require adding Windows Forms related assemblies to WPF project and as a result will impact startup performance as well as memory footprint or the overall project.